# Services module, custom endpoint & authentication

Tags: users, services

I have a have setup a custom endpoint via services and a REST server the custom end point looks like this,

`https://website.local/api/v1/druaplsquare`

The custom endpoint is built using the following code,

**drupalsqaure.module**

```
function drupalsquare_services_resources() {
  $resources = array();
  $resources['drupalsquare'] = array(
    'operations' => array(
         'create' => array(
             'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/drupalsquare'),
             'callback' => '_job_resource_create',
             'args' => array(
                 array(
                     'name' => 'node',
                     'optional' => FALSE,
                     'source' => 'data',
                     'description' => 'The node data to create',
                     'type' => 'array',
                 ),
             ),
             'access callback' => '_drupalsquare_resource_access'
         ),
         'delete' => array(
             'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/drupalsquare'),
             'callback' => '_job_resource_delete',
             'args' => array(
                 array(
                     'name' => 'jobref',
                     'optional' => FALSE,
                     'source' => array('path' => 0),
                     'description' => 'The job reference to delete',
                     'type' => 'string',
                 ),
             ),
             'access callback' => '_drupalsquare_resource_access'
         ),
    ),
  );
  return $resources;
}
```

**resources/drupalsquare.inc**

```
<?php

function _drupalsquare_resource_access() {
    return TRUE;
}

//function _drupalsquare_resource_retrieve($uid) {
//  $account = user_load($uid);
//
//  if (isset($account->data['checked_in'])) {
//      return array(
//          'uid' => $account->uid,
//          'name' => $account->name,
//          'last_checkin' => $account->data['checked_in'],
//      );
//  }
//  else {
//      return FALSE;
//  }
//}

function _drupalsquare_resource_checkin($JobReference, $date = NULL) {
    die(print_r($JobReference));
//  $account = user_load($uid);
//  $account->data['checked_in'] = is_null($date) ? REQUEST_TIME : $date;
//  user_save($account);
    return TRUE;
}

function _job_resource_create() {
    die("create");
}

function _job_resource_delete($jobref) {
    die("here");
}
```

I am making a cURL request this is endpoint, but I am first of all authenticating a user, and getting a token, I am then sending this token in the request header, however the endpoint above is returning,

> Access denied for user anonymous

Can anyone see any reason as why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you checked Services modules permissions?

Comment: Authenticated user can do all the actions they should be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code
Replace `'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/drupalsquare'),`
with `'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'NAME_OF_YOUR_MODULE', 'name' => 'resources/drupalsquare'),`
It seems you're wrongly defining your INC file.